# Modify and Delete GCP Dataflow Jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

Once you "CREATE JOB FROM TEMPLATE", is there a way to modify or delete that job.

[GCP Dataflow Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03rYP.png)

Comment: what do you want do modify? The params or the code?

Comment: you can only stop the job, but it will not be 'deleted' - is that a problem?

Comment: @Pablo, ah..yeah. If you want to cleanup your job lists and remove jobs that failed, how are you supposed to do that? I've created some temporary batch jobs that I won't need anymore. So they will just stay out there forever? Why wouldn't you want a delete function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to delete Dataflow jobs.

On the other hand, regarding modify them,  as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataflow/jobs), there is no possibility to use gcloud for update the job.

Nevertheless, the Apache Beam SDKs provide a way to update an ongoing streaming job on the Dataflow managed service with [new pipeline code](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline).

In addition, another option you have is using [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/update), where you can find Java example.

Finally, [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/153109774) you can find a feature request to recreate a job with gcloud.